# I am trying to get output like below using pythone code...any suggestions?

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice, list-comparison

I am trying to get output like below using pythone code...any suggestions?

list=["ABCPMCABCCMD","CMDABC"]
list2=["ABC","CMD"]

output:
[ABCABCCMD,CMDABC]

Comment: What shoud be the result of `lst=["ABCMD"]` ?

Comment: if this is your 1st list then output should be [ABC]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the How To Ask a Good Question page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` module:

```py
import re

list1 = ["ABCPMCABCCMD", "CMDABC", "ABCMD"]
list2 = ["ABC", "CMD"]

r = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(w) for w in list2))
out = ["".join(r.findall(word)) for word in list1]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['ABCABCCMD', 'CMDABC', 'ABC']
```